# How to catch GET variables in a htaccess Rewrite Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm sorry i can't get out of this alone... after a successful payment users are redirected to this URL on my site:

```
https://www.example.com/orders/?token=AAA&status=OK
```

i would like to grab token and status and assign them to GET variables but i'm truly unable to do so, this is my current RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^orders/?token=([^/]+)&status=([^/]+)$ /orders.php?lang=it&token=$1&result=$2 [L]
```

in `orders.php` i have this line:

```
echo "token: ".$_GET['token'];
```

but of course in console i always get

> ```
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: token in /orders.php on line 3
> ```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match the query string using the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, you need to use a `RewriteCond` directive and check against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. However, in this instance, you MUST also ensure that `MultiViews` is disabled (otherwise `orders.php` will be called without any URL parameters).

Try the following instead:

```
# MultiViews MUST be disabled
Options -MultiViews

# Rewrite URL with query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^token=([^&]+)&status=([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^orders/$ orders.php?lang=it&token=%1&result=%2 [L]
```

Note the use of the `%1` and `%2` backreferences (as opposed to `$1` and `$2`) that get the values from the captured groups in the preceding *condition*, as opposed to the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to help me out, i'll try to adapt your suggestion, probably there's some configs i have to do as now i get an internal server error,  due to the RewriteCond line.

Comment: @matteo Sorry, there was a typo in the regex. Should be `([^&]+)`, not `([^&])+)`. The regex would have failed to compile, resulting in the Internal Server Error (500 response). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes!!! Here we go!! Thank you so much, it was truly out of my reach :) Now i just have to check that this doens't mess with my other rules, but i think that in case i can just move it to the bottom of my htaccess. Thanks again.

Comment: @matteo You're welcome. "i can just move it to the bottom of my htaccess" - yes, providing there are no rules that might conflict above it.